# Android: Issue while capturing image through Android's Camera

Tags: android

I am using Android's camera in my application. Camera is being called by using

```
Intent captureImage = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureImage.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(captureImage, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

I am catching result on

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}
```

Problem is when I capture an image, I didn't get anything back onActivityResult() but if I cancels camera activity I am getting result as -1. 
It means my method are working but something goes wrong after capturing an image and fails to return image uri.

Can anybody tell me what's the problem???
Thank You.

Comment: Did you check logcat for any messages? Could be something related to ImagefileUri.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Snippet :

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
} 
}
```